# SQL Server Integration Services with WF4

Tags: ssis, workflow-foundation-4

I have to export date from exel to Sql with following requiremetns
1. Schema in excel is different than SQL. Like one row in excel will be inserted as multiple rows in SQL according to buisness logic and values present in the cells.
2. Before inserting data in sql i have to apply buisness rules. In some cases the data is not valid for insertiion in sql.

Can I use SSIS with WF4 in. LIke with SSIS I will extract and load the data and transformation will be done by Wf4/

Answer (score 2):

To strictly answer the question, maybe. The 60 second read I had of WF4, is that it ships with with VS 2010 and uses .NET 4 framework. 2008 R2 only supports the 3.5 framework in script tasks and components.

That said, if you continue adding layers and use something like WCF, then you should be able to provide a web service interface and then you can do whatever work flow stuff inside the service.

But, doing any of that seems crazy to me. SSIS is an ETL engine. ETL is Extract, Transform and Load so you're adding what is probably unnecessary layers of complexity to your work. Need to split 1 row into many rows in SSIS? That could be a multicast, unpivot or script task depending on your needs.

Conversely, if you have all the work done in WF4 already, write the reader and writer yourself-it's trivial.